# Alphabetically sort a taxonomy.php template by post title

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, custom-post-type-archives

Simply put, is it possible to sort a taxonomy.php template via the same methods you can with something like `wp_query` so that the archive shows all posts in an ascending order alphabetically by title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can `query_posts` and `orderby=title`:

```
<?php //*The Query*//
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
query_posts($query_string . '&post_type=YOUR-POST-TYPE&posts_per_page=1&orderby=title&order=asc&paged='.$paged);
if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();
?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else : ?>

<?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

more info: [WP_Query#Order/Orderby Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)

Comment: I guess theres no danger in using query_posts then correct? Im just always weary of using it versus `wp_query` since it seems to potentially cause more additional issues with paging, or effecting other loops on the same page, etc.

Comment: Yes @Mr.Brown , you will not have a problem if you reset your query, if you have any conflicts with other queries, build a custom query and include the "orderby" and "order" parameters

Comment: Ok thank you, Ill give this a try and report back.

Comment: Ok this works for sorting the posts as I wanted but now Im loosing paging as a result. How might I construct a custom query similar to the one your referring to as an alternative? Thanks.

Comment: Apologies, what I meant to say is that when using `posts_per_page` paging seems to not work correctly...but when using the Reading Settings instead of `posts_per_page` I seem to get the correct results.

Comment: I have update the code now, set the page before the loop: $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

Comment: @Mr.Brown is this ok? i hope you have found the answer!

Comment: Yes thank you. Can you extrapolate on whats going on in that line though?

Comment: With "get_query_var('page')" you can get the current page number from the query. More info you can find here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var